# Django test client gives 404 when trying to get a public file from google cloud storage. Works fine when using requests lib

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a public file on cloudstorage with public `url = https://storage.googleapis.com/xyz/abc.pdf`

```
import requests
requests.get(url)  # gives status_code=200
```

But in django test, following gives 404 error:

```
self.client.get(url)  # status_code=404
```

Answer (score 1):

Test should be able to run without network access. Django's Test Client is made to work within that restriction and to test your Django application, not your network access.

[Read Docs Before Use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client):

> The test client is a Python class that acts as a dummy Web browser, allowing you to ***test your views*** and interact with your Django-powered application programmatically.